# How do I cache a custom module that has points?

Tags: caching

I am making a site with users that have points. I have a custom module that calculates points for each user, but the page is slow when is calculating the points in real time, so what I want to do is making a cache the points so they don't need to be calculated anytime someone open the page. The page will be cached; if users want the status for their points, they can update them pressing the "Update" button. So I will write a function for that button to clear the cache.

Comment: Notice that you are stating facts without asking any explicit question. (The question title doesn't count as explicit question.) Clearly, you need tp cache some data that take time to be calculated. What you don't say is what you tried, what you get and why it was not the result you expected, what documentation you find, and what you didn't understand in that documentation. With this question, users can just point out the functions Drupal uses for caching, but that is something it can be easily found on api.drupal.org.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Drupal cache API to set and get the data from cache.

Assuming D7, The following resources have some good information on that:

- https://www.lullabot.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-caching-data-in-drupal-7
- https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/caching-to-improve-performance/caching-overview

For example:

```
function MYMODULE_function() {
  global $user;
  $user_point_data = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__ . $user->uid);
  if (!isset($user_point_data)) {
    // User per user cache id for points.
    $cid = 'user_point_data:' . $user->uid;
    if ($cache = cache_get($cid)) {
      $user_point_data = $cache->data;
    }
    else {
      // Do your expensive calculations here, and populate $user_point_data
      // with the correct stuff..
      cache_set($cid, $user_point_data, 'cache');
    }
  }
  return $user_point_data;
}
```

You can then clear the cached data, based on specific user id or all items, with:

[`cache_clear_all`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7.x)

```
// Clear all user point data from cache
cache_clear_all('user_point_data', 'cache', TRUE);
// Clear specific user point data from cache
$cid = 'user_point_data:' . $GLOBALS['user']->uid;
cache_clear_all($cid, 'cache');
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggest, Ill try and see what can i get.

Comment: I would also add, from experience, you might want to create your own cache bin for this purpose.